# How do I pan in EagleCAD with an Apple MagicMouse

Tags: eaglecad

I'm using a MacBook Pro with OS X Mountain Lion, but can't figure out how to pan the schematics?

Comment: Interactive panning in Eagle is done by holding down the middle mouse button.

Comment: [Snark] - Get a real mouse? I've tried to use a magic mouse, and found it absolutely horrible.

Comment: I agree @Snark, the Magic Mouse, despite its hefty price tag, is often coming short of quite a bit.

Comment: on a trackpad, it seems to work if i put my mouse over the scroll bar indicators and scroll with 2 fingers

Comment: The question is about a MagicMouse, not a trackpad, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be solving the problem okay for me:

http://magicprefs.com/

Answer (score 5):

You need a mouse with a standard no-frills middle click button for Eagle. The center click on my Thinkpad doesn't work either because it uses some nonstandard scroll thing with the Synaptic driver where it's treated like scrolling on the touchpad instead of a true third mouse button.

You might want to give Kicad a shot instead, it lacks a normal middle mouse pan function in favor of more zooming in and out that normally bugs me, but it could work out to be more intuitive with the MagicMouse -- the nonstandard middle mouse on my Thinkpad ends up working as a pan+zoom function.

Comment: Bummer, that's just horrible, thanks for mentioning KiCAD, I'll take a look into it. ;)

Comment: If you end up liking KiCAD but miss the libraries you had in Eagle check out http://www.kicadcloud.com/. A buddy of mine built it and maintains it for free for the KiCAD community. Doesn't charge a cent. Pretty nice site.

Answer (score 1):

I run Eagle on OSX. Eagle 5.x has no way to pan without a real middle button, but 6.x pans with the normal scrolling gestures. I expect that a magic mouse would work the same way as a trackpad in this regard.