# Changing sheet size in Eagle

Tags: eaglecad

How can I change the sheet size in Eagle? I want to do this both for board schematics and the package design area. The latter is especially annoying.  I'm inputting a BGA part and I can't zoom in and scroll to the outer edges of the package, although I've been able to input it all through a script.

edit: I'm using Eagle Hobbyist 6.4.0 on a 13" MacBook Air OS X 10.8.3 with touchpad.

Comment: I just restarted the application after closing both the schematic, and board. I opened it again and it seemed to have adjusted for the objects I had put outside of the scroll boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

EAGLE determines the size of your schematic by a bounding box that can hold all of your symbols. So if you put a dummy part or a little bit of text in the top right, it will expand the limits of where you can scroll.

On the Mac, two-finger scrolling works for EAGLE.

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work for me. I put some text outside invisible boundaries but still can not see the scrolling bars until I get close enough (bits of text are far beyond the displaying area for this moment)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly related: [How do I pan in EagleCAD with an Apple MagicMouse](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/53578/10157)

Given a normal mouse, the way to pan the camera is to hold the middle mouse button and move the cursor. According to one of the answers to that question, you can use gestures on your touchpad to pan around.

Comment: That's not what I mean.  I mean the amount of usable, scrollable area available in the sheet.  I've found a partial workaround: I can zoom into a given region if I zoom way out then use zoom select.  But once I'm zoomed in, I can scroll sideways and repeatedly zooming in/out is very tedious.

Comment: Oh hrm, in that case can you edit your question with some more info? Version of Eagle, any nonstandard mouse you might be using (including laptop touchpads), etc. I've never had an issue with that before, I've made designs far too large for one sheet in the free version and panned around just fine.

Comment: Edited.  I wonder if it is a problem with the Mac version.